# C#: Replace a single / with a *single* \

Tags: c#, string, replace

I found a lot of posts answering similar questions (like "How to replace `\` by `/`" or "How to replace `\\` by `\`". I understand all those, but none of them solves my special problem. Here it is:

I'm reading a path string from registry, which contains "`///`" instead of "`\`" (easy to replace), but also "`/u00xy`" for unicode characters. To successfully parse the string with the correct unicode character I have to replace the `/` with a *single* `\`. But every possible way (`string.replace` or `regex.replace`) results in "`\\u00xy`" instead of "`\u00xy`"!

Or, I get an error like "*`Unrecognized escape sequence`*". For example:

```
str.Replace("/u00", @"\u00")   // results in "\\u00"
```

Whilst:

```
str.Replace("/u00", "\u00")    // gives an error.
```

I'm out of ideas!

Comment: Where are you observing the `\\u00` results? Is it possible the debugger is playing tricks on you? It's been known to do that.

Comment: +1. The hover-over-a-variable visualiser in Visual Studio's debugger will do exactly this, IIRC.

Comment: Did you try escaping the backslash? = str.Replace("/u00", "\\u00");

Comment: I understand your question and I know that the debugger will show it that way. The problem is that the string itself definitely contains the double backslash where I need a single one.

Comment: You might want to put together a quick sample in VB.Net - As there is no string escaping in vb, you might be able to see your issue better.

Comment: @LastCoder The OP did escape it by using the `@` symbol. (it prevents needing the escape every `\` instance)

Comment: @WolfRuland: Not from the code (and input) you gave it won't. Please read my answer and prove it to yourself with the sample program I've given.

Comment: @LastCoder: Yes, I did - and it replaces the slash with a double backslash. The Replace is not the problem; the *internal* representation of the unicode sequence in the string *must* have a single backslash, which I can't create.

Comment: Please update your sample with value of `str` that reproduces the problem. (like `var str = "x/u00y"`) and also show length and values of each character in resulting string.

Comment: @WolfRuland: Even with a bit more understanding of what you're doing, I'm still *extremely* dubious of something really doubling the backslash, and I still think your ideas about an "internal representation of the unicode sequence" are off.

Comment: What I love most about this question and the attempted answer is the way that the StackOverflow editor/presentation itself keeps interfering with it, adding a third (or is it fourth?) layer of confusion over the general confusion of C escaping, .Net escaping, VS IDE/Debugger escaping, Unicode encoding, etc.  Tower of Babel indeed...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe something like this should work for you:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Globalization;

namespace Test
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ConvertUnicodeEscapes("aa/u00C4bb/u00C4cc/u00C4dd/u00C4ee")); //  prints aaÄbbÄccÄddÄee
        }

        private static Regex r = new Regex("/u([0-9A-F]{4})");
        private static string ConvertUnicodeEscapes(string input)
        {
            return r.Replace(input, m => {
                int code = int.Parse(m.Groups[1].Value, NumberStyles.HexNumber);
                return char.ConvertFromUtf32(code).ToString();                    
            } );
        }       

    }
}
```

As Jon pointed out, this is not simply replacing a '/' with a single '\'. You can't really do that since '\' is the escape character. First, we have to match the groups "/uXXXX". Then we convert the string hex portion (XXXX) into an integer in utf32 (i.e. unicode). Finally, we get the character corresponding to that utf32 code.

Comment: Cool - looks great! I'll try that approach; it might save me from writing my own parser :)  (Will inform you whether it works!)  THANKS!

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: Now I understand what you're trying to do, it's not at all surprising that it works. You're not talking about an "internal" representation of a string - you're really asking for the C#-specific string literal parsing rules to be applied at execution time.

If you write:

```
string x = "\u0041";
```

... that creates a string containing a single character ('A'). The fact that in the original *source code* it was represented as a Unicode escape sequence doesn't affect the string at all. So the above code is *indistinguishable* at execution time from:

```
string x = "A";
```

Now it, sounds like you want to parse a string containing a slash, followed by a `u`, followed by four hex digits, into a single character. You'll have to do that yourself, or find another library which does it - you shouldn't expect `string.Replace` to do it for you.

In other words, it's vital that you understand the difference between the data itself and the source code representation of data.

---

You claim:

```
str.Replace("/u00", @"\u00")
```

> results in "\u00"

No, it really doesn't. If you write the results out to the console, you'll see there's just one backslash.

I strongly suspect you're looking in the debugger, which shows an escaped view.

Demonstration code:

```
using System;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string input = "x/u00y";
        string output = input.Replace("/u00", @"\u00");
        Console.WriteLine(output); // Result: x\u00y
    }
}
```

This code:

```
str.Replace("/u00", "\u00")
```

will indeed fail, because the string literal `"\u00"` is invalid. It's an unterminated Unicode character escape sequence.

Comment: Thanks, I see that clearly. But unfortunately it doesn't solve my problem. It's about the *internal* representation of the unicode sequence. In your example the full string will not show the unicode character but only '\u00C4' instead of Ä (for example).

Comment: Here is an example of what I mean:

The string I read from the registry might be: 'H/u00C4GAR'. This will have to translate to 'HÄGAR'. I'm trying to do this by changing the string internally to 'H\00C4GAR'. Is there a better way?

(Sorry if I have problems describing my problem properly!)

Comment: +1. I think adding dump of each of individual characters of resulting string may be beneficial.

Comment: @WolfRuland: Oh, in that case you're not talking about an internal representation in .NET at all. You're talking about C#-specific Unicode escape sequences. You can't just replace a character within a string and expect C#-specific parsing rules to be applied. You'll have to parse the string yourself.

Comment: @WolfRuland, do you want to replace custom Unicode encoding (/uXXXX) with character corresponding to XXXX?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: Yes, indeed! :)

Comment: @WolfRuland: See my edit. Basically, you shouldn't expect String.Replace to do this for you.

Comment: Thanks, Jon - I understand. Guess I will have to write my own parser using a list of all possible unicode characters :(

Thank you for your time!

Comment: @WolfRuland: Why would you need to have a "list of all possible unicode characters"? You can parse the four hex digits to a 16-bit unsigned integer, and then convert that to `char`.

Comment: You're right, of course :)  (mike z posted a perfect solution.)  Thanks

Comment: @WolfRuland: Yup - but do you understand exactly what's going on now? It's very important to understand the difference between what you write in source code and what's actually in a string. (I still don't understand how you ever actually got a string with a double backslash...)